# Allow only (English & Arabic) in UTF-8 code

Tags: php, perl, unicode, utf-8

I am looking for a regex to change all non-english and/or arabic into underscore "_"

Currently I have the following code which works but I think that I've got the wrong unicode

range as it allows Chinese & other languages I don't require in my script.

```
$title=~tr/[a-z0-9_\x7f-\xff]/_/cd;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's a nice explanation of Unicode regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), including the [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)](http://www.pcre.org/) library.

Answer (score 9):

If you're seeing bytes between `\x7f` and `\xff`, your application is probably working with UTF-8 bytes, not Unicode characters. Read [`perldoc perlunicode`](http://p3rl.org/UNI), then [`decode()`](http://p3rl.org/Encode) your strings before trying to work with them on this level.

Once that's done, you should be able to search for English and Arabic characters with something like:

```
/[\p{ASCII}\p{Arabic}]/
```

See [`perldoc perluniprops`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) for other Unicode properties you can use.

Comment: Users beware, `ASCII` is much too restricted to be useful for English, do not just add this to your codebase without further examination what is needed for the specific text you're working with. Add more props in an iterative fashion. Alas, there is no magic universal collection of properties for English.

Comment: @daxim: Aside from diacriticals, is there anything major that the `ASCII` prop excludes?

Comment: Various quotation and other punctuation characters. Also see http://98.245.80.27/tcpc/OSCON2011/gbu/gbu.html#A%20Sample%20Unicode%20Corpus.

Comment: English is not ASCII.  This is a myth.  English uses the Latin script, not the ASCII block.  You want `[\p{Latin}\p{Arabic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}]`. See [my three OSCON talks on Unicode](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The range of the Arabic (Indic) digits is: \x{0660}-\x{0669}

The range of the Arabic letters is: \x{0621}-\x{063A}\x{0641}-\x{064A}

The range of the Arabic vowels including "Tatweel" is: \x{0640}\x{064B}-\x{0652}

The range of the Arabic puncation is: \x{060C}\x{060D}\x{061B}-\x{061F}\x{2E2E}\x{066A}-\x{066D}

Comment: But, luckily, no-one needs to know all of that when you can just query the Unicode properties of the characters.